# Proof in the context of Galois theory that quintics and above can't be solved by the trigonometric and exponential function

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have been studying Galois theory as of late and recently I came across [this proof](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/394/ArnoldQuintic.pdf) in the context of Complex Analysis which not only prove the unsolvability of the general quintic and higher degree polynomials using radicals but also using trigonometric and exponential functions.

Is there a proof in the context of Abstract Algebra/ Galois theory that is equivalent? Preferably this proof should follow the same line of reasoning as the Abel-Ruffini theorem (the version that I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) specifically).

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but where exactly is the theorem about trigonometric and exponential functions? I haven’t read through the note in detail, but after a quick scan I can’t find the thing you’re talking about

Comment: @qwertiops it is mentioned in the abstract and as the first thing in the section about the insolvability of the quintic.